# How to resolve error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) in Xcode5

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios7

```
duplicate symbol _flag in:
/Users/anuragarwt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FacesFactory1919-azxixfmcaofhiubsbjsjuvwyehhy/Build/Intermediates/FacesFactory1919.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacesFactory1919.build/Objects-normal/i386/LoginFacesFactoryViewController.o
     /Users/anuragarwt/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FacesFactory1919-azxixfmcaofhiubsbjsjuvwyehhy/Build/Intermediates/FacesFactory1919.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FacesFactory1919.build/Objects-normal/i386/EditProfileFacesFactoryViewController.o ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386 clang: error: linker
command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try first to Clean the project.

Comment: i have cleaned the project - as soon as i include the following line of code it generates this error







-(IBAction)Checkbutton:(id)sender;
{
if(flag==0)
{
    UIImage *btnImg=[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkboxchecked.png"];
    [ checkRember setBackgroundImage:btnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    flag=1;
}
    else
    {
    
        UIImage *btnImg =[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"];
        [ checkRember setBackgroundImage:btnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        flag=0;

    
    }


}
1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, when we import .m file instead of .h file then the error of duplicate symbol occurs.
Secondly, i just changed the variable int flag to int i , v for different classes cleaned the project and run it worked.